# How to merge multiple facet results into a list of objects with one attribute

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

## The situation:

In my mongodb aggregate pipeline I have a `$facet` stage which produces multiple
output fields e.g.: `pipe_1` and `pipe_2`.

The result has the following form:

```
{
  pipe_1: [{"key": "a"}, {"key": "b"}, {"key": "c"}, {"key": "d"}],
  pipe_2: [{"key": "a"}, {"key": "B"}, {"key": "d"}]
}
```

## Wanted result

My question is now, how do I get the following result from it:

```
[
  {"key": "a"},
  {"key": "d"}
]
```

I want only the keys, that are in both list and no duplicated should be in
the result. Preferably I would like to have an answer without any slow group stages and 
it must work for more than two list.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [$setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            result: {
                $setIntersection: [ "$pipe_1", "$pipe_2" ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/chTNQqEQIO7)

Comment: Thank you very much, it was exactly what I needed.
My final code looks like this:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZdA_Sfx-MhI